# Place Popup to custom position

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I am using Popup with custom position, what I want is to place Popup outside the right corner of the screen. I have tried it with Custom positions using CustomPopupPlacement[], but no use. Is it possible to do so?
I am attaching an image so that to clear what I expect.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A popup cannot be placed off screen:

> For security reasons, a Popup cannot be hidden by the edge of a screen.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596.aspx for a ton of information about Popup placement, including handling the off-screen placement case.